# Why does /users/{id}/answers, which returns an array of answers, have an optional 'answers' flag?

Tags: bug, status-completed, parameters

I would assume that if you are requesting the route '/users/{id}/answers' that you wish to receive some answers.

Comment: Do you also generate questions to ask here too?

Comment: @SMARK - working on it. soapi borg is evolving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation for `/users/{id}/answers` has been updated.